# How to toggle an event on a Class node list

Tags: javascript, loops, events, click

I'm trying to toggle a javascript event on a class node list. I've done a simplified version of the problem below.

The initial event is being executed, but the second event to toggle the button back to red doesn't seem to be working? JS and link to Codepen below.

Codepen is here: https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/EXmzbd?editors=1010

JS

```
  var clicked = false;

  var $mainMenuButton = document.getElementsByClassName('desktopmenubutton');

if (clicked === false) {
     for (h = 0; h < $mainMenuButton.length; h+=1) {
      $mainMenuButton[h].addEventListener('click', function (e){
        e.currentTarget.style.background = "black";
        clicked = true;  // change clicked state to true
      });    
   }
} else {
    for (i = 0; i < $mainMenuButton.length; i+=1) {
      $mainMenuButton[i].addEventListener('click', function (e){
        e.currentTarget.style.background = "red";
        clicked = false;
      });
    } 
}
```

Comment: you either assign a *activate* or an *unactivate* eventlistener to your elements. That does not really fit your problem

Answer (score 1):

You only need one event listener to get this to work.

```js
var $mainMenuButton = document.getElementsByClassName('desktopmenubutton');


for (h = 0; h < $mainMenuButton.length; h += 1) {
  $mainMenuButton[h].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor == "red" || e.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor == "") {
      e.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    } else {
      e.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
* {font-family: arial;}

.desktopmenubutton {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white
}

.button2 {
  left: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="desktopmenubutton button1">Button 1</div>
<div class="desktopmenubutton button2">Button 2</div>
```